# Prometheus does not scrape metrics from Cloudfront - Timestamp issue?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-cloudwatch, prometheus

I am using [cloudwatch-exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/cloudwatch_exporter) to scrape metrics from CloudWatch and expose them in its `localhost:9106/metrics`.

The configuration for this is the following:

```
 region: us-east-1
    set_timestamp: false
    metrics:
       - aws_namespace: AWS/CloudFront
         aws_metric_name: TotalErrorRate
         aws_statistics: [Average]
         aws_dimensions: [DistributionId, Region]
         aws_dimensions_select:
          Region: [Global]
```

And I can indeed see the fetched metrics:

```
$> curl localhost:9106/metrics
# HELP aws_cloudfront_total_error_rate_average CloudWatch metric AWS/CloudFront TotalErrorRate Dimensions: [DistributionId, Region] Statistic: Average Unit: Percent
# TYPE aws_cloudfront_total_error_rate_average gauge
aws_cloudfront_total_error_rate_average{job="aws_cloudfront",instance="",region="Global",distribution_id="E1XXXXXX",} 26.666666666666668
aws_cloudfront_total_error_rate_average{job="aws_cloudfront",instance="",region="Global",distribution_id="EXXXXXXX",} 0.0
aws_cloudfront_total_error_rate_average{job="aws_cloudfront",instance="",region="Global",distribution_id="E38XXXXXX",} 0.0
aws_cloudfront_total_error_rate_average{job="aws_cloudfront",instance="",region="Global",distribution_id="E6XXXXXXX",} 100.0
# HELP cloudwatch_exporter_scrape_duration_seconds Time this CloudWatch scrape took, in seconds.
# TYPE cloudwatch_exporter_scrape_duration_seconds gauge
cloudwatch_exporter_scrape_duration_seconds 14.487444391
# HELP cloudwatch_exporter_scrape_error Non-zero if this scrape failed.
# TYPE cloudwatch_exporter_scrape_error gauge
cloudwatch_exporter_scrape_error 0.0
```

However, Prometheus does not scrape them, and outputs the following logs:

```
level=warn ts=2018-06-20T07:00:37.578384931Z caller=scrape.go:932 component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=kubernetes-service-endpoints target=http://100.106.248.21:9106/metrics msg="Error on ingesting samples that are too old or are too far into the future" num_dropped=24
level=warn ts=2018-06-20T07:01:36.821700134Z caller=scrape.go:932 component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=kubernetes-service-endpoints target=http://100.106.248.21:9106/metrics msg="Error on ingesting samples that are too old or are too far into the future" num_dropped=24
level=warn ts=2018-06-20T07:02:35.593731873Z caller=scrape.go:932 component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=kubernetes-service-endpoints target=http://100.106.248.21:9106/metrics msg="Error on ingesting samples that are too old or are too far into the future" num_dropped=24
```

Specifically:

> msg="Error on ingesting samples that are too old or are too far into
> the future"

My guess is that CloudWatch being located in Virginia, and our `cloudwatch_exporter` and Prometheus being in EU, there is a Timestamp difference preventing Prometheus to scrape these metrics. 
Hence my guess to use `set_timestamp: false` as pointed in this [Merge Request](https://github.com/prometheus/cloudwatch_exporter/pull/102).

However, that does not work.
I am not a professional of Prometheus, and may be it ils wrongly configured. How can I further investigate?